# CSS: Menu with clickable logo inside

Tags: css

```
http://jsfiddle.net/2esybgmo/
```

```css
html {

  margin: 20px;

  background: url("Images/background.png")center no-repeat fixed;

}

ul,

img {

  margin: 0;

  padding: 0;

  vertical-align: middle;

}

.menu,

.dropdown-menu {

  list-style-type: none;

  background-color: white;

  border-radius: 7px;

}

.menu li {

  margin-left: -4px;

  display: inline-block;

  text-align: center;

  border-right: 1px solid #eaeaea;

}

.menu li:first-child {

  background-color: #4b424f;

  border-top-left-radius: 7px;

  border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;

}

.menu li a {

  color: black;

  display: block;

  height: 100%;

  padding: 17px 25px;

  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;

  font-size: 12px;

  text-decoration: none;

  margin: 0;

}

.menu li:hover .dropdown-menu {

  display: block;

}

ul.dropdown-menu {

  position: absolute;

  border-top-right-radius: 0;

  border-top-left-radius: 0;

  border: none;

  display: none;

}

ul.dropdown-menu li {

  display: block;

  text-align: left;

  margin: 0;

  border: none;

  border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;

}

ul.dropdown-menu li:last-child {

  border: none;

}

ul.dropdown-menu li:first-child {

  border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;

  background-color: White;

  border-top-left-radius: 0;

}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#"><img src="Images/logo.png" alt="logo" height="28" width="117""></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">The Product</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Order Yours</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Support </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Read our FAQ</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Post a Support Ticket</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Orders & Shipping</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Get in touch with us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <p></p>

  <div style="visibility: hidden;" class="flexslider">

    <ul class="slides">
      <li>
        <img src="Images/background.png" alt="img1" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="Images/background.png" alt="img2" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="Images/background.png" alt="img3" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like the gray lines (border-right) in li elements fill the whole ul area (as well as the  tags) like it used to do. After adding the image into the list there are a few pixels "missing" and I think the problem is because the image itself is a bit higher than the text inside  tags. How to do it without changing image or text size?

Comment: we are missing the image, but i believe you should reset vrtical-align to li since you use inline-block dispay  ... if pixel missing are vertical, horizontal would be another issue about white-space from code :)

Comment: Why are you using an image for the background of your menu list options , when the background is a single color? You can use background-color in css for that: background-color:  #383043;

Comment: @SouthPole what we see here is a color not the image he uses. check the src link :)

Comment: @GCyrillius I don't understand the idea you said.

Comment: @SouthPole Im not using an image for background, I have white logo and the first-child of the list has a background color